# how to export results when running selenium ruby webdriver scripts to output files from command prompt ruby window

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, rake

Currently, I'm running all selenium scripts in my test suite (written by Selenium Ruby Webdriver) at one time by using rake gem in "Start Command Prompt with Ruby" terminal.

To do this I have to create a file with name "rakefile.rb" with below content and just call "rake" in my terminal: (I have known this knowledge based on the guide of a person in my previous posts).

```
task :default do
    FileList['file*.rb'].each { |file| ruby file }
end
```

However, running will be terminated if there is one script got failure when executing.

Anybody please help guide me how to modify "rakefile.rb" so that if there is one script failed, then system will ignore it and continue to run the next script in my test suite ?

Also, could you please suggest me a way to write all results when running scripts to one output file ?, or the result of each script is put in each output file and a output file will display the list of scripts failed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run all my tests inside a unit framework.  I use test-unit myself but you could also use rspec.  This also gives you the ability to add assertions to your code and then have it be reported by the unit framework.  If one test fails or errors you can move on to the next test.

a simplified version of my rakefile looks like this

```
require 'rake/testtask'

#this will run all tests in directory with no dependencies 
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['FAL*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end

#or you could run individual files like this

task :FAL001 do 
  ruby "FAL001.rb"
end
```

and every test case looks like this

```
require "test-unit"
gem "test-unit"
require "selenium-webdriver"

class FAL001 < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def testFAL001 #methods that begin with test are automatically run 
    #selenium code goes here 
    assert_true(1 == 1)
  end
  def test002 
    #another test goes here 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `begin` and `rescue` to catch any failures in your test scripts.

Something like

```
begin
 raise "Ruby test script failed"
rescue
 puts "Error handled"
end
```

Which in your case would be something like

```
task :default do
    FileList['file*.rb'].each { |file| 
    begin
      ruby file
    rescue
      puts "Test script failed because of #{$!}"
    end 
    }
end
```

and as of writing to a file that would be something like

```
task :default do
    $stdout = File.new('console.out', 'w')
    $stdout.sync = true
    FileList['*.rb'].each { |file| 
    begin
      ruby file
    rescue
      puts "test script failed because of #{$!}"
    end 
    }
end
```

What that does is override $stdout to redirect the console output.

Comment: big big thanks to you, base on your guide and just add once more log message, now I'm able to run all test scripts in my test suite, and then display the list of failed tests after finish executing scripts, the "rakefile.rb" file now is:               task :default do
    $stdout = File.new('console.out', 'w')
    $stdout.sync = true
 FileList['test*.rb'].each { |file| 
    begin
      ruby file
 rescue
   puts "The following tests reported unexpected behavior:"
      puts "#{file} \n"
 end 
    }
end

Comment: However, Could you please guide me more the way to modify "rakefile.rb" to be able to export the content of executing each failed tests to each output file ? It means that I expect the content of executing each my script will be written to output files instead of displaying on my Ruby terminal (ex: when I'm running the test script "test_GI-1.rb", then the content of executing this script will be written to an output file "test_GI-1.out" instead of showing in my Terminal. Thanks again for your great guide.

Comment: something like this `ruby example.rb > test.txt`

Comment: Yes, I know the way like ruby test.rb >> test.txt as you mentioned, it works as expected when I type it in Ruby terminal. However, it does not work at all when I include this thing in rakefile.rb. I will open a new post for you and someone guy to help me more easier. Thanks again.