# how to write selenium ruby webdriver test results from Ruby terminal to output files

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, rake

Currently, I'm running all selenium scripts in my test suite (written by Selenium Ruby Webdriver) at one time by using rake gem in "Start Command Prompt with Ruby" terminal.

To do this I have to create a file with name "rakefile.rb" with below content and just call "rake" in my terminal: (I have known this knowledge based on the guide of a person in my previous post [how to export results when running selenium ruby webdriver scripts to output files from command prompt ruby window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881610/how-to-export-results-when-running-selenium-ruby-webdriver-scripts-to-output-fil/13881878#13881878)).

```
task :default do
    $stdout = File.new('console.out', 'w')

    $stdout.sync = true


    FileList['test*.rb'].each { |file|
    begin
      ruby file

     rescue

      puts "The following tests reported unexpected behavior:"
          puts "#{file} \n"
     end
     }
end
```

However, I do not know how to modify "rakefile.rb" to be able to **export the content of executing each failed tests (that being displayed on my Terminal) to each output file** ? It means that I expect the content of executing each my script will be written to output files instead of displaying on my Ruby terminal (ex: when I'm running the test script "test_GI-1.rb", then the content of executing this script will be written to an output file "test_GI-1.rb.out" instead of showing in my Terminal.

I **modified my "rakefile.rb" to something like ruby file >> test.rb.out, but it does not work at all** (this thing only works when I type directly the thing like ruby test.rb >> output.out on my Ruby Terminal). Anybody please guide me a way. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this out, but I guess this should work

```
task :default do
FileList['test*.rb'].each { |file|
 begin
   system("ruby #{file} > #{file}.log")
  rescue
   puts "The following tests reported unexpected behavior:"
   puts "#{file} \n"
  end
}
end
```

Based on new requirements -

**UPDATE**

---

```
task :default do
    logfile.new("console.out", "w")
    FileList['test*.rb'].each { |file|
     begin
       system("ruby #{file} > #{file}.log")
      rescue
       logfile.puts("The following tests reported unexpected behavior:")
       logfile.puts("#{file} \n")
      end
      }
end
```

Comment: thanks again for your great answer, this solution has resolved my main question. However, when using "system" method to write all content to output log files, **the lines of code after "rescue" become NOT work**. So, I'm **NOT able to print the list of Failed scripts** in "console.out" file **as before**. So, could you please give me way to have all output files as you suggested, but still able to print the list of failed scripts in a file like "console.out" file ? much appreciate.

Comment: I'm thinking that exporting the result of each script to output log files caused no exception thrown on the terminal. Therefore, the lines of code after "rescue" no longer work any more, So nothing is written to the file "console.out". However, I will try to research it. thanks so much for great guides.

Comment: @battleship, you could try failing one of the scripts on purpose and then check which file gets written with what.

Comment: I tried to make some scripts failed on purpose, but they are NOT written to "console.out" file, it means the lines of code after "rescue" no longer work. In case, I just use the line of code: ruby file after "begin" (not including export results to output files), the list of failed scripts displayed on "console.out" as expected.

Comment: Rescue will only display standard errors and not standard outpout. So if your script *errors* out then the output will be written in console.out, but if the script *fails* with a legitimate test failure then it will be written in the log file. I would recommend using a library like http://rubydoc.info/gems/ci_reporter/1.8.3/frames to parse your test results and convert them Junit style. This test report is pretty much a standard test output.