# How to generate results after selenium test in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium

I have recently started using ruby to write tests for selenium but I would like a way for the tests to be exported into a results file.

For an example of what i mean. I was exporting the tests from the IDE to html and then running them using

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -htmlSuite *firefox http://google.com /path/to/suite.html /path/to/results.html
```

in the command line and it would run the suite.html and then post the results in results.html

Is this possible in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone has already taken on the same challenge before. See this article [how to export results when running selenium ruby webdriver scripts to output files from command prompt ruby window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881610/how-to-export-results-when-running-selenium-ruby-webdriver-scripts-to-output-fil?lq=1).

You may have to write up a rake file, but I believe it will be a good experience that will make you better acquainted with ruby and how to go about selenium testing with it.